# ASP.NET MVC: Generating dynamic sitemaps for SEO purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I want to add/remove urls to sitemaps whenever a user deletes or submits information.

I have a few questions:

1. Should I put slugs on the URL in the sitemap? `Products/Details/1/my-slug` -> URL works without slug.
2. Should I Use an action to generate a sitemap? In `robots.txt` I'll link to this action.
3. If not action, are there libraries that allow me to easily edit sitemap.xml files?
4. Sitemaps has a limit to the # of URLs and size, is there a way to automatically create more sitemaps when this limit is met? I'd have to also update the `robots.txt` and add more links to sitemaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ASP.NET MVC SiteMap Provider project](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) has support for automatically generating the sitemap XML for search engines, including the ability to [break up large sitemaps into multiple files](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exporting%20the%20sitemap%20for%20search%20engine%20indexing&referringTitle=Home).